# Why is this a* algorithm is slower than Djikstra's?

Tags: python, search, a-star

I need to show how a* is quicker than Djikstra's using the graph below. I wrote the a* search function and then called it using a set of heuristics and then with all heuristics set to 0 (which is equivalent to Djikstra's). While the actual search with a* is more efficient, five steps to Djikstras seven, the recorded time it takes it to run is always higher, even averaged across numerous runs. The a* run with actual heuristic values is doing less so shouldnt it be faster? (Maybe my code is wonky?)

```
import heapq as heap

#Create graph

graph =    {
    'A': {'B':5},
    'B': {'C':8,'D':9,'E':3},
    'C': {'B':8,'G':2},
    'D': {'B':9,'F':2},
    'E': {'B':3,'I':4},
    'F': {'D':2,'I':3},
    'G': {'C':2,'H':3,'I':6},
    'H': {'G':3,'J':4},
    'I': {'E':4,'F':3,'G':6,'J':2},
    'J': {'H':4,'I':2},
    }

hcost =    {
    'A': 875.008571,
    'B': 717.54094,
    'C': 720.151373,
    'D': 685.286801,
    'E': 596.030201,
    'F': 434.165867,
    'G': 420.107129,
    'H': 190.779978,
    'I': 179.744263,
    'J': 0,
    }

hcost1 =    {
    'A': 0,
    'B': 0,
    'C': 0,
    'D': 0,
    'E': 0,
    'F': 0,
    'G': 0,
    'H': 0,
    'I': 0,
    'J': 0,
    }

def astar_algo(graph, start, target, hc):

    #We set the cost for all nodes from the source
    cost =  {vertex: float('infinity') for vertex in graph}
    #The distance from the source to itself is 0
    cost[start]=0
    
    #We create 
    fcost={vertex: float('infinity') for vertex in graph}
    fcost[start]=hc[start]
    
    #We create a list of nodes to record the path i.e. the solution to the problem
    path=set()
    
    #We create a set to hold visited nodes
    visited=set()

    #We create a priority queue which contains distance to node,node,path and add our start node
    priorityq = [(fcost[start], start, [])]

    #While our priority queue isn't empty
    while priorityq:
        
        #pq0 =  [priorityq[idx][0] for idx in range(0, len(priorityq), 1)] 
        #pq1 =  [priorityq[idx][1] for idx in range(0, len(priorityq), 1)]
        #print(f"Priority Queue: {list(zip(pq0,pq1))}\n")
        #We pop out the highest priority element of the queue i.e. the shortest distance entry
        (dist,current_node,path) = heap.heappop(priorityq)
        
        #print(f"dist {dist} current node {current_node} \tpath {path}\n")

        #Add it to the path list and record it as being visisted
        path = path+[current_node]
        visited.add(current_node)

        #We check if its our target, if it is we break the while loop with a return value
        if current_node==target:
            #We return a tuple with the target node and the cost to it as well as the path to it
            return (current_node,cost[current_node]), path
            
        #If it isnt our target node then we check all its adjacent nodes
        for adj_node, weight in graph[current_node].items():
            
            #If we've visited the node we move on to the nest
            if adj_node in visited:
                continue
            
            #If the node is new we calculate the cost to it by adding the weight to it to
            #the cost for the current node
            new_cost = cost[current_node]+weight
            
            #calculate fcost = graph cost + heuristic cost
            new_fcost = new_cost+hc[adj_node]
            
            #If the cost to the adjacent node is shorter than its recorded cost
            if cost[adj_node] > new_cost:
                #We update its recorded cost
                cost[adj_node]=new_cost
            
            #If the fcost to the adjacent node is shorter than its recorded fcost
            if fcost[adj_node] > new_fcost:
                #We update its recorded cost
                fcost[adj_node]=new_fcost
                #And it to the priority queue
                heap.heappush(priorityq, (new_fcost,adj_node,path))

    return (0,0),'none'
                              
start='A'
target='J'

st =  perf_counter_ns()
cost,path = astar_algo(graph,start,target,hcost)
print('Time elapsed in nanoseconds {}\n'.format(perf_counter_ns() - st))

st =  perf_counter_ns()
cost,path = astar_algo(graph,start,target,hcost1)
print('Time elapsed in nanoseconds {}\n'.format(perf_counter_ns() - st))

if path=='none':
    print("There is no solution available.")
else:
    print(f"The distance to {cost[0]} is {cost[1]}.")
    print (f"The shortest path from {start} to {target} is",end=" ")
    print(*path, sep="->")
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it's related to your performance issues, but your heuristic is a very strange one. Generally you want an estimate of the distance from a given node to the goal node. But your heuristic costs are much lower than any of the weights in your graph, and you're adding two of them to the cost so far for no obvious reason.

Comment: Two problems: 1) you can't just run something once and look at a nanosecond timer. see https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html

Comment: 2) I haven't looked at the details of this algorithm, but when we say an algorithm is more efficient, we usually mean as the dataset grows in size. You just have one tiny graph here. In this case, it looks like a* does more work to get a payoff down the line, but with such a tiny graph that doesn't really help?

Comment: I've changed the values back to what they were originally, which was the straight line distance from each node to the goal. I'd got confused about how the heuristic shouldnt "overestimate" the distance. 

I was adding two of them because I'd mistakenly thought the heuristic cost was cumulative like the graph cost instead of being a constant cost.

Correcting those errors unfortunately still has the a* resolve slower than Djikstras

Comment: I meant it was more efficient in that it finds the solution in 5 rather than 7 iterations while storing less information in memory. Unfortunately the problem for the assignment set the graph so theres not a lot I can about that.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion of using timit, using

t = timeit.Timer(lambda: astar_algo(graph,start,target,hcost)) 
print (t.timeit(1000000))

t = timeit.Timer(lambda: astar_algo(graph,start,target,hcost1)) 
print (t.timeit(1000000))

Returns the expected result i.e. its quicker with an actual a* implementation

Comment: I assume there was supposed to be an "import heapq as heap" and you got rid of the print statement inside the function when you were timing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't just run a tiny code fragment once and take a nanosecond reading, even if your computer has an accurate nanosecond timer (which it probably doesn't). Memory caching and random chance of what else is happening in the computer are going to dominate the measurement (if it's accurate, which it's not).

Fortunately, python provides a timeit module which automates the process of running code over and over, and recording the time. I changed some variable names for clarity, but here is a snippit using timeit to get the times:

```
# I renamed some variables for clarity
from timeit import timeit

astar_time = timeit('cost, path = astar_algo(graph, start, target, hcost_astar)', globals=globals(), number=10000)
print ('astar time    {}'.format(astar_time))

djikstra_time = timeit('cost, path = astar_algo(graph, start, target, hcost_djikstra)', globals=globals(), number=10000)
print ('djikstra time {}'.format(djikstra_time))
```

> astar time   0.4517704
> djikstra time 0.5962602